# how can i get specified columns in Zend_Model_Dbtable class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a database with columns id,name,description,date. i want to select only two columns from my data to fill my zend select form element. is there in zend any method to fetch all data of specified columns. please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**select**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('table')//table name
       ->columns(array('vch_no'))//place your column here
       ->where()//condition array
       ->order();//order column name
```

For example:

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                    array('product_id', 'product_name'));
// Build this query:
//   SELECT p."product_id", p."product_name"
//   FROM "products" AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$objDb                  =   Zend_Registry :: get('db');//You need to setup the database configurations ready in the registry before using it
$select                 =   $objDb->select();
$select                 ->  from('tablename',array('column1','column2'));
$select                 ->  where()
                        ->  order();
$rows                   =   $objDb->fetchAll($select);
```